# C program is claiming file is not there, but it is?

Tags: c, file, input, io

So I have this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MASK 0x07FF
#define TABLE_SEZE 32
#define LITTLE_SIZE 8
#define SIZE 256
#define DEBUG 1

int main() {


    unsigned v_addr = 0;

    FILE *inFilePtr = NULL;
    FILE *outfilePtr = NULL;
    char inFileName[SIZE];
    char outfileName[SIZE];

    printf("Enter the name of the file we are working with!.\n");
    fgets(inFileName, sizeof(inFileName), stdin);

    //open 'er up
    inFilePtr = fopen(inFileName, "r");
    outfilePtr = fopen(outfileName, "w");

    if (inFilePtr == NULL || outfilePtr == NULL){

        printf("Could not open the file.\n");
        exit(1);

    }//end of if

}//end main
```

I want it to read a file, but it keeps on saying that the file is not there.

The problem is, the file is in the current directory.  What is going on?

Comment: Where is the file that you want to read is located? It should be in the application path.

Comment: Where do you set the `outfileName`? And how do you know what the error is, you print the same message no matter the actual error. Use e.g. [`strerror`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strerror) to get the actual error. Oh, and you don't even know *which* `fopen` failed, just that at least one did.

Comment: While you're at it, I think `getcwd()` may be somewhat telling to you.

Comment: It is in the same directory as the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change

```
fgets (inFileName, sizeof(inFileName), stdin);
```

into

```
scanf ("%[^\n]s", inFileName);
```

It will work perfectly !

Comment: This change introduces a [buffer overflow exploit](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Buffer_Overflow) into the program.  If someone types more characters than will fit in `inFileName`, the original code is safe, but your suggested code will clobber the stack.

Answer (score 3):

Note that fgets() typically returns a string including the \n so you would need to remove that if there is one.

e.g.

```
char* p = strchr(inFileName, '\n');
if ( NULL != p ) 
{
  *p = '\0'; 
}
```

you also need to set outFileName to something

e.g.

```
strcpy( outFileName, "_" );
strcat( outFileName, inFileName );
```

Comment: I'd like to upvote this answer, but `fgets` does not always put a `\n` at the end of the line -- for instance, if the last line of a file doesn't end with a trailing newline, or if the line was longer than the space provided, it just stops.  (Also, when you put spaces on the inside of `()` or `[]` you make the baby Jesus cry.)

Comment: @Zack you are of course right, i have modified my answer.